# Remove Duplicates concatenating columns

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have the data in Table A like this as i/p

```
Col A                      |    Col B    |    Col C
PG_1100000357_1100000356   |  1100000357 |    1100000356 
PG_1100000356_1100000357   |  1100000356 |    1100000357
PG_10909099_12990909       |  10909099   |    12990909
PG_8989898_79797987        |  8989898    |    79797987   
PG_8989898_79797987        |  8989898    |    79797987
```

I need to write a query to recieve the o/p as -

1) Remove the exact duplicates from the i/p when it  matches with another record. (examples 4th & 5th record)
2) We need to consider concatenation of `COl B`, `COl C` to concatenation of `Col c`, `Col B` and remove that duplicate also. (1st and 2nd record)
note :- `COl A` is arrived by CONTACT(PG_,Col B,'_',Col c) and dont worry about that

```
    Col A                      |    Col B    |    Col C
PG_1100000357_1100000356   |  1100000357 |    1100000356 
PG_10909099_12990909       |  10909099   |    12990909
PG_8989898_79797987        |  8989898    |    79797987
```

Could you please help me? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--Oracle SQL: row_number().
--Least and Greatest functions will work regardless Col_B and Col_C have number or varchar2 data type
with s (Col_A, Col_B, Col_C) as (
select 'PG_1100000357_1100000356', 1100000357, 1100000356 from dual union all
select 'PG_1100000356_1100000357', 1100000356, 1100000357 from dual union all
select 'PG_10909099_12990909'    , 10909099  , 12990909   from dual union all
select 'PG_8989898_79797987'     , 8989898   , 79797987   from dual union all
select 'PG_8989898_79797987'     , 8989898   , 79797987   from dual)
select Col_A, Col_B, Col_C
from
   (select s.*,
    row_number () over (partition by least(Col_B, Col_C), greatest(Col_B, Col_C) order by Col_B desc) rn
    from s
   )
where rn = 1;

COL_A                         COL_B      COL_C
------------------------ ---------- ----------
PG_8989898_79797987         8989898   79797987
PG_10909099_12990909       10909099   12990909
PG_1100000357_1100000356 1100000357 1100000356
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not right to hold the same data in the multiple columns. The values of the `Col_B` and `Col_C` are already exist in `Col_A`, you just need to split them, and then apply group by with `least` and `greatest` functions as @akk0rd87 suggested and considering the previous tag `oracle` :

```
with Table_A(Col_A) as 
(
  select 'PG_1100000357_1100000356' from dual union all
  select 'PG_1100000356_1100000357' from dual union all
  select 'PG_10909099_12990909'     from dual union all
  select 'PG_8989898_79797987'      from dual union all
  select 'PG_8989898_79797987'      from dual 
), t as
(
  select regexp_substr(Col_A, '[^_]+', 1, 1) col_one,
         regexp_substr(Col_A, '[^_]+', 1, 2) col_two,
         regexp_substr(Col_A, '[^_]+', 1, 3) col_three
    from Table_A 
)
select max(concat(concat(col_one||'-',least(col_two,col_three)||'-'),
                                      greatest(col_two,col_three)))
       as Col_A,
       least(col_two,col_three) as Col_B, greatest(col_two,col_three) as Col_C
  from t
 group by least(col_two,col_three), greatest(col_two,col_three);
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/LJI22706)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The below SQL query returns result as you expected

```
 ;WITH CTE AS( SELECT    ColA, ColB, ColC,  
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN ColB > ColC THEN ColB ELSE ColC END ORDER BY ColB) RN 
 FROM TableA )
 SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC FROM CTE WHERE RN =1
```